# Is there a way to get notified on a phone if my pc crashed or rebooted?

Tags: windows-10, crash, reboot, notifications

My PC sometimes crashes and just reboots and I don't know why(this could be a separate question). The Problem is that i have downloads and programs running 24/7. Most of the time i am not at my pc and especially during the night. Is there a way to get notified via phone or e-mail after my pc reboots? I want to be able to react as fast as possible.

Comment: One answer is to use a command-line e-mailer, such as one of those described [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/sending-email-using-command-line-useful-for-downtime-alert-notification/), set to run on start-up.

Comment: As AFH has suggested, the easiest solution would be to use a command line e-mailer. Then you could set up a new task using Task Scheduler, call it something like Reboot Alert, set the user as system, the trigger at Startup and set the actions to run a script calling the command line e-mailer with the details to connect to your mail server and the message you want to send.